# Postgres - assign custom secuence to a table

Tags: postgresql

I created a `test_seq` and I want to assign my secuence to a table.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE test_seq;
```

and implementation:

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE drop_permission_seq;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION before_insert_drop_permission() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  _id  TEXT;
BEGIN
  
  PERFORM 
  CASE
        WHEN length(nextval('drop_permission_seq')::TEXT) < 2 THEN _id = 'DP-000000'||(nextval('drop_permission_seq')::TEXT)
        WHEN length(nextval('drop_permission_seq')::TEXT) < 3 THEN _id = 'DP-00000'||(nextval('drop_permission_seq')::TEXT)
        WHEN length(nextval('drop_permission_seq')::TEXT) < 4 THEN _id = 'DP-0000'||(nextval('drop_permission_seq')::TEXT)
        WHEN length(nextval('drop_permission_seq')::TEXT) < 5 THEN _id = 'DP-000'||(nextval('drop_permission_seq')::TEXT)
        WHEN length(nextval('drop_permission_seq')::TEXT) < 6 THEN _id = 'DP-00'||(nextval('drop_permission_seq')::TEXT)
        WHEN length(nextval('drop_permission_seq')::TEXT) < 7 THEN _id = 'DP-0'||(nextval('drop_permission_seq')::TEXT)
        ELSE _id = 'DP-'||(nextval('drop_permission_seq')::TEXT)
    END ;

  -- Now assign the order id and continue with the insert
  NEW.drop_permission_name = _id;
  RETURN NEW;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER assign_drop_permission_key
  BEFORE INSERT ON public.drop_permission
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE before_insert_drop_permission();
```

But every time I try to insert, I get the error:

> ERROR:  null value in column "drop_permission_name" violates not-null
> constraint

Why is not inserting the primary key? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

```
ALTER TABLE ... ALTER col
   SET DEFAULT to_char(nextval('drop_permission_seq'), 'DP-0000000');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sequence next value as the default value for id field:

```
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('test_seq');
```